# What jquery selectbox plugin is used in trulia.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

Does any one know what jquery plugin was used in this page of trulia.com in the refine search section. I think this is a good selectbox plugin and i've googled it and with no luck. I would really like to use this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean that big green element with `Bed`- and `Bath`-selectboxes, it seems they don't use any plugin for those, just pure HTML and some CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have peeked into the code on trulia.com, and it does not look like they are using a plugin. It is simply an ordinary selectbox, which is styled with wrapper elements.

There are some code in the polarbear-home.js javascript file, which sets/removes focus to the select.

```
$(".select-wrapper>select").bind("focusin", function (c) {
    $(this).prev().addClass("focus")
});
$(".select-wrapper>select").blur(function (c) {
    $(this).prev().removeClass("focus")
});
```

But, my guess is, that this is no public available plugin, but some wrapper styling, and some some js/jquery code to do the focus/unfocus styling.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot. I'm new to webdevelopment. How I wish I could make plugins like those, A hybrid select/dropdown/range input would just be superb.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/blog/introducing-the-jquery-plugin-selectboxit/).  I just released it last week.  DailyJS also wrote about it here http://dailyjs.com/2012/04/24/jquery-roundup/

Comment: Wow, this is really good. Thanks sir. I would try to use this awesome jQuery plugin. Have not explored it yet though but does this support text input aside from the options on the dropdown? It would be very fantastic if it does. Sorry for the much delay reply, had a very bad internet connection problem.

Comment: Currently you can put text that is different from the options by setting the defaultText option.  In the 0.6.0 release (will be out tomorrow), you will also be able to specify text by adding an HTML 5 data attribute to the original HTML Select Box Element.